# Highcharts fill in scatter plot data with 0s

Tags: java, javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter plot as shown below (edited to show what I want). I have data over time (blue dots) but the days not containing data I would like to fill in with 0s (black dots). It does not seem that there is a function to do this in [high charts docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts). What would be the best way to go about filling in the data? My charts are made using JSON.

My JSON is in the format `{x:value,y:value}`, x being the date in milliseconds, y being the actual value.

```
[{"x":1398952144380,"y":3},{"x":1401976144380,"y":30},{"x":1402062544380,"y":9},{"x":1402148944380,"y":11},{"x":1402235344380,"y":30},{"x":1402321744380,"y":23},{"x":1402408144380,"y":1},{"x":1402580944380,"y":28},{"x":1402667344380,"y":32},{"x":1402753744380,"y":17},{"x":1402840144380,"y":35},{"x":1402926544380,"y":39},{"x":1403012944380,"y":6},{"x":1403185744380,"y":30},{"x":1403272144380,"y":27},{"x":1403358544380,"y":14},{"x":1403444944380,"y":24},{"x":1403531344380,"y":16},{"x":1403617744380,"y":9},{"x":1403790544380,"y":2},{"x":1403876944380,"y":21},{"x":1403963344380,"y":46},{"x":1404049744380,"y":33},{"x":1404136144380,"y":38},{"x":1404222544380,"y":6},{"x":1404308944380,"y":28},{"x":1404395344380,"y":34},{"x":1404481744380,"y":28},{"x":1404568144380,"y":16},{"x":1404654544380,"y":25},{"x":1404740944380,"y":9},{"x":1404913744380,"y":13},{"x":1405000144380,"y":19},{"x":1405086544380,"y":28},{"x":1405172944380,"y":20},{"x":1405259344380,"y":23},{"x":1405345744380,"y":12},{"x":1405518544380,"y":20},{"x":1405604944380,"y":22},{"x":1405691344380,"y":30},{"x":1405777744380,"y":27},{"x":1405864144380,"y":25},{"x":1405950544380,"y":16},{"x":1406123344380,"y":13},{"x":1406209744380,"y":23},{"x":1406296144380,"y":20},{"x":1406382544380,"y":31},{"x":1406468944380,"y":31},{"x":1406555344380,"y":3},{"x":1406728144380,"y":12},{"x":1406900944380,"y":13},{"x":1406987344380,"y":22},{"x":1407073744380,"y":22},{"x":1407246544380,"y":8}]
```

I would prefer to do this server side in Java.

[image]

Comment: For each day return data - if no data for that day return 0 in whatever you are using to hold your data. Without knowing how/where your data is stored it is the best I can do.

Comment: @wergeld , I added more on the data I use

Comment: How is the data stored is what I mean. What are you using to create your jSON?

Comment: How about adding this missing points in JS? Simple `for()` should be enough.

Comment: @PawełFus what would the for loop look like? i have to calculate the milliseconds of 6 months ago, milliseconds of today, loop between it adding 8.64kk milliseconds to the 6monthsago milliseconds, and for each day loop through my object and see if the milliseconds match up, if they do take my `y` data, otherwise use 0? Actually; I think writing this out got me to solve the problem. If you write a loop with what i said and it works ill accept your answer. thanks!

Comment: @PawełFus I tried a if statement, inside a for loop, inside a while loop. It output all 0s, which means my milliseconds aren't matching up on each day I think. Still working on it. I strongly believe highcharts should support this problem itself ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle this case by lib. How do I know what is the distance between two points? In your case I guess it's 2days, but I need to calculate this. Anyway, see my answer - it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend array of points this way: http://jsfiddle.net/7VNwk/4/

```
    var interval = 172800000, //interval between two points - two days?
        dataLength = data.length, 
        startingPoint = data[dataLength-1].x - 162 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // half year from last point
        extendedData = [],
        i = 0;

    while(i < dataLength) {
        var actual = data[i];
        if(startingPoint < actual.x) {
            extendedData.push({x: startingPoint, y: 0});  
        } else {
            extendedData.push(actual); 
            i++;
        }
        startingPoint += interval;
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'   
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            data: extendedData
        }]
    });
```

Of course, it depends on your interval between points. As I can see from your data, it's about 2days.